# Magento 2.1.8 Custom Module Routes

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, template, router

I am trying to create new pages for a custom module I am developing.

the base page for my module is:

```
www.mywebsite.com/forum
```

I wanted to add three more pages:

```
www.mywebsite.com/forum/category
www.mywebsite.com/forum/category/post
www.mywebsite.com/forum/user
```

I am having a few issues with doing this.

1. to reach the `/forum/category` and `/forum/user` page, It is making me use the url /forum/index/category and forum/index/user. How can i remove the `"index"` part from the URL?
2. When I access the page `/forum/index/category/post`, it is loading up the template .phtml file for `/forum/index/category` and not the one I have create for Post. The layout .xml file for this page points to the correct template .phtml file. What could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your controller name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create three folder in Controller according to your url.

**www.mywebsite.com/forum/category**

```
Namespace\Moduelname\Controller\Category\Index.php
```

**www.mywebsite.com/forum/category/post**

```
Namespace\Moduelname\Controller\Category\Post.php
```

**www.mywebsite.com/forum/user**

```
Namespace\Moduelname\Controller\User\Index.php
```

Comment: Cheers Qaisar, Exellent answer.